# where to put entity related methods?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, oop

Asp.net-mvc, using nhibernate.

my vs.net layout is like:

- /dao  (1 class per entity for database work, using repository)
- /model
- /mappings
- /factory  (db factory that provides access to each entities Dao)

Now I need utility methods, not sure where to put them.

example:

- CartItems.cs
- CartIemsDao.cs

Now say I have a method like:

```
IList<CartItem> items = CartItemsDao.GetById(234)
```

Now I want to create a method that populates a `Dictionary<int,CartItem>` from a given `IList<CartItem>`.  Should I create a CartItemManager.cs for this?

And what would a 'Service' type class be used for?  e.g. CartService.cs

I believe someone said earlier a 'service' type class is to wrap multiple calls/logic for Dao's etc.  Is that what it is?

Answer (score 1):

There are several styles, you can definitely create a "helper" type that has all the static methods you need but this is not very discoverable from an API standpoint.

I would create these static methods on the data access objects themselves - this is much easier to discover.  Of course nothing is stopping you from delegating the *implementation* of these static methods to some internal helper type.

*Also as a side note:* I don't personally care for the style of appending "DAO" or other similar identifiers to the names of types.  The type is what it is so I would suggest that you leave off the "DAO" (but that has nothing to do with your question).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that what you describe is a "Service", which I usually define loosely as [potentially] any operations I might want to make on entities that don't really fit into the entity itself (which practically by definition includes cross-aggregate operations).

To state it generally, you want transform a list of items into a dictionary of items using some function upon the item to derive the key.

With .Net generic typing, you could make a service for this so general it would fit best in a utility type of library that fits into the infrastructure layer where any other layer can utilize it.

```
public class CollectionToDictionaryMappingService {
  IDictionary<TKey, TValue> Map<TKey, TValue>(ICollection <TValue> items, Func<TKey, TValue> keyAccessor) 
  {
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    foreach (TValue val in items) {
      dictionary.Add(keyAccessor(val), val);
    }
    return dictionary;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose to view it from a layered architecture point of view.

**App layers**

It depends how are you architecturing you app. I generally use two diferents layers for DAO and for Business/Logic.

In an information system logic layer generally replicates the methods of DAO, because the methods needed for implementing the use cases are get data / update data... much the same that the DAO layer. BUT I think it's important to separate them because you can add extra logic in the logic/business layer, things more complex (or composite) than the DAO.

**List -> Dictionary case**

I don't know if you need that method for business logic. If it's the case maybe the method can be private to some business class that uses it. Or it can be a public method of a protected helper class in the business layer.

If it's not the case I'd publish it in the business layer anyway.

BUT, if I follow the layered point of view... The service layer should provide methods for implementing the use cases. It is: it should provide the data structures needed. in this case: it should provide the dictionary.

So:

- *the convert method should be private to the business layer*

or

- *be a generic conversion method like the proposed by **qstarin***